# Dependency management for SLF4J and Logback

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, dependency-management, logback

I'd like to start using SLF4J with Logback. I read over Logback's online [documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/documentation.html) and am now ready to add the JARs to my repo and try it out.

But I'm at a loss! What JARs do I need? I downloaded that latest SLF4J (1.7.5) and expected to see *something* like `slf4j-logback.jar`, but don't see anything of the sorts. I've read that Logback contains a "native implementation" of SLF4J, but don't know exactly what this means, or if it also implies that I don't even need `slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar` on the classpath.

So I ask: to use the latest Logback (1.0.13), what JARs do I need? I took a look at the Maven central repo [for logback 1.0.13](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|ch.qos.logback|logback-site|1.0.13|jar) and don't see any dependencies listed, so that didn't help me at all. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to add logback-classic to your pom

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.13</version>
    </dependency>
```

it will transitively add the following two:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.13</version>
</dependency>
```

and

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

See https://logback.qos.ch/setup.html#mavenBuild for more information.

Comment: Thanks! but is also expecting org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all ? any idea ..?

Comment: You probably just need to add the optional dependency:

`<dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
  <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>`

source: https://logback.qos.ch/setup.html#mavenBuild

Comment: Thank you, I have been trying to figure this out for hours!