# logs doesn't getting printed using Logback using ConsoleAppender

Tags: java, logging, logback

I wrote a simple program in which I am using `Logback`. My intention was to use ASYNS which internally will use STDOUT.

**Here is the Java code listing:**

```
package com.example;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
public class LogBackMainApp {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = 
    LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogBackMainApp.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
       LOGGER.info("Hello world");
       LOGGER.info("Hello world again");
       Thread.sleep(5000);
   }
}
```

**The below is the configuration file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="60 seconds" >
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <!-- %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %thread %-5level %logger{0}:%L 
            If you required class name ,enable %logger{0}:%L -->
        <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %thread %-5level - %msg
            %n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<appender name="ASYNC-STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
    <queueSize>1</queueSize>
    <discardingThreshold>20</discardingThreshold>
    <neverBlock>true</neverBlock>
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</appender>
<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNC-STDOUT" />
</root>
```

I am defining `root` logger which would cater to my `com.example` package, and it refers to `ASYNC-STDOUT`, which internally uses `ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender`.

As per my current understanding, it should be able to log to console. However, nothing is coming. Is there something wrong in my code or configuration OR do i miss to understand the concept altogether.

Answer (score 0):

If you use maven have a look: [Dependency management for SLF4J and Logback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660749/dependency-management-for-slf4j-and-logback). Maybe you're missing a required dependency. Sl4j is only an abstraction for you're real logger implementation which has to be added as dependency.

Comment: Yes I have all the dependencies in place, in fact, File logger works fine.